# Mono C# application instantiating C++ library classes with boost components

Tags: c#, c++, linux, boost, mono

I have been researching for a while now if it is possible to write a C++ library with a class that can be instantiated in a mono application on Linux.

My requirement is that i need to use a boost algorithm and I need to instantiate one object and have it persistent for the life of the c# application and call a number of functions on it.

I'm happy to write wrapper classes, or use a COM component or whatever tech I need to make this work. But I'm not sure which technology will be best suited for my needs, or if the use of boost will be completely prohibitive.

Can anybody demystify this for me?

COM/ATL - SWIG - CLI - CXXI?

Which is right for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the new [CppSharp](http://github.com/mono/cppsharp) project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't think the link is going to change in a long time, the CppSharp author is part of the Mono team (Xamarin employee)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will definitely look into this when I'm less up against the clock. For the moment I've created a C Interface layer that creates my object statically inside the library scope and calls c functions to pass the static object it's data and retrieve results from it. Thank you for your help! Nic.